# How to install ROS (Robotics Operating System) on Raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, ros

How i will able to install ROS (Robotics Operating System). I want to install ROS on my raspberry pi 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## ROS (Robotics Operating System) install on raspberry pi

#### Hardware requirement

1. Raspberry pi 2/3
2. SD card 16 GB to 32 GB
3. Card reader
4. HDMI monitor (optional)
5. Keyboard (optional)
6. Mouse (optional)

### Download

**Download ROS Image (Ubuntu mate)**

7. There are many of Image list item you need to choice one
8. https://downloads.ubiquityrobotics.com/pi.html
9. It take some minutes about 1 GB file. When download completed Unzip ROS image into a folder

   **Download Win32DiskImager**
10. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bs2cClNa-LKqeoK8Kmcm-DWhFKsQw2dj/view?usp=sharing
11. when download complete then install Win32DiskImager
12. Open Win32DiskImager

### Image write into SD Card

13. Inser SDCard into your pc
14. Open Win32DiskImager
15. Set image path using red circle button
16. Select SDcard using green circle
17. Everything is ok then click write
18. It will takes some minutes

### Start ROS operating system

- Insert SDcard into Raspberry pi
- Power up
- Psername: **ubuntu**
- Password: **ubuntu**

### Test ROS

- Press **Ctrl+Alt+T** for open terminal
- **Open terminal**

  $ rostopic list

Output

```
/battery_state
/cmd_vel
/diagnostics
/joint_states
/joy
/left_error
/motor_node/parameter_descriptions
/motor_node/parameter_updates
/right_error
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/statistics
/tf
/tf2_web_republisher/cancel
/tf2_web_republisher/feedback
/tf2_web_republisher/goal
/tf2_web_republisher/result
/tf2_web_republisher/status
/tf_static
```

#### Thanks install Completed